# create content dynamically with JS from external PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, iframe

I'm trying to create a popup window with quite a bit of content, so I've put the content into a separate .php file and I use the following javascript to get the effect I want:

```
$('#popup').show();
var u = $("#username").html();
$('#popup').html('<iframe src="content.php?u='+u+'"></iframe>');
```

This works well, except that I have a close function for when the user hits the escape key:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
    $('#popup').hide().html('');
    } 
});
```

My problem is that once the popup opens, and the user clicks within the iframe, the escape button no longer closes the window because I'm using the iframe.

Is there a better way in Javascript to include an external php file dynamically like this, or is there a way I can make the escape button function work even if the iframe has been clicked within?

Comment: From the same domain? use Ajax

Comment: I didn't know I could use ajax that way. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.load()`:

```
$('#popup').load('somefile.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not advisable to use `iframe`, use `ajax`. If you still want to use `iframe` then you have to store the `popup` in `top`, e.g. add below code in main `php` file

```
top.popup = $('#popup');
top.popup.show();
var u = $("#username").html();
top.popup.html('<iframe src="content.php?u='+u+'"></iframe>');
```

And below code in main `php` and `content.php`

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        top.popup.hide().html('');
    }
});
```